# Using NodeJs Style function callbacks with ArangoJS 3.x

Tags: node.js, database, arangodb, arangojs

Is it possible to use NodeJs like function Callbacks with ArangoJs 3.x;
I have seen that ArangoJs 3.x using `.then` method (promises)..
But I am using NodeJs 4.4 .. so i can't use `.then` method there.. Can I use nodejs like function callbacks for arangojs 3.x ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use the `.then` method there?

Comment: because .. there is no support for javascript promisses (.then) in node 4.x here you can see .. freature support.. http://node.green/

Comment: There is no native support for the `Promise` object but if the ArangoJs library implements them on their own you can still use `.then`

Comment: No, Now ArangoJS provides native support for promises .. that's why `.then` method is there.. and working perfectely with node 6.3 .. but my question is .. is , still is it possible to use nodejs like function call backs instead of then.. i asking this for the sake of backword compability to work with older versions of nodejs(where no promise support..)

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. Have you tried to use `.then`? Also, node 4.4 _does_ have native promises

Comment: I have already tried `.then` method on node 4.4 .. I know that wouldn't work promises on node 4.4 ... My question is can i still use ArangoJs with node 4.4.. means can i use `node like callbacks ` instead of promises (`.then`) methd.. if so.. please give me an example to create collection in ArangoDb using Arangojs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [ArangoJS github page](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs):

```
// ES2015-style
import arangojs, {Database, aql} from 'arangojs';
let db1 = arangojs(); // convenience short-hand
let db2 = new Database();
let {query, bindVars} = aql`RETURN ${Date.now()}`;

// or plain old Node-style
var arangojs = require('arangojs');
var db1 = arangojs();
var db2 = new arangojs.Database();
var aql = arangojs.aql(['RETURN ', ''], Date.now());
var query = aql.query;
var bindVars = aql.bindVars;

// Using a complex connection string with authentication
let host = process.env.ARANGODB_HOST;
let port = process.env.ARANGODB_PORT;
let database = process.env.ARANGODB_DB;
let username = process.env.ARANGODB_USERNAME;
let password = process.env.ARANGODB_PASSWORD;
let db = arangojs({
  url: `http://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}`,
  databaseName: database
});

// Using ArangoDB 2.8 compatibility mode
let db = arangojs({
  arangoVersion: 20800
});
```

Isn't that exactly what you were looking for?

Comment: First of all i want to thank for this answer... But this is not exactly what i want.. I have seen it already.. But how can i write same to create a collection.. The same is not working for collections.. if you can please give example to create collection using node js style clalbacks.. because creating collection varies from other stuf..

Comment: @shivaraj try `db.collection('someCollection').create(function (err, res) {...})`?

Comment: Thank you very much @AlanPlum , now i get clear with that.. and please change the answer that only explains our main problem.. give collection example too..